# Browser With Filesystem Write Capabilities

Tags: browser

I am unsure if this is a question, or how to frame it as such... but there is this thing that has been bugging me for a while now...

I find webUI to be extremely easy to implement, and so when I want to slap a UI on a small script I have written I usually just go with HTML,JS, and CSS.  What frustrates me is the sandboxing precaution implemented in the browser that forbids me from writing to the disk.  It limits my use of the script in conjunction with the UI to a new session each time, terminating any work from previous sessions.

I understand why that is in terms of the web and malicious code being run on your machine, but I feel like there is a benefit in having an HTML,JS, and CSS rendering 'browser' that can write to disk... maybe in exchange it will be prohibited from surfing the web, or better, say firefox or chrome could recognise that the files are located on the local system and so allow local system write access?

It can be such a hassel to have to go through a server-framework-gateway just for some simple local io storage.

Some practical uses...

-When I am at an early development stage, i just want to flesh out the project without fleshing out the entire system structure, or having to rent out a host and putting it up there, or altering the server config to include another localhost port.  Just open the folder containing the project and fire up the index.htm in the browser.

-Also, it would be cross platform without any hassel.  Balls to deciding between kde or gtk or mfc or whatever other unnecessary dependencies.  I want to write a small program and be able to just eMail my old man a zip file that he unzips and loads an index.htm into his browser and it just works.  The ability to just do something without me having to explain to him: ok, so first you have to download this, then this, then install them. ok, now you have to change this file to configure this thing to loo...what? o, what does configure mean?  well, it means exactly what it means: configure, you basically have to configure the way this programs works so it works the way you want it to... right, yeah i know it should just ship working but it does this is different from fixing it, this is how it is supposed to work.  actually its quite brilliant that it works this way its just that it seems more complicated than it is.  Boom.  I've lost him.

Can you explain to me why I'm out of my mind on this, or are there applications that do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you want to achieve, but at least part of what I think you mean could be done with localstorage. See e.g. http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html.

Comment: yeah, i was always turned off by local storage because of the limitations attached to it, perhaps my prejudice is unnecessary... i'll have to tool around with it to see if it fills my needs, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: You could also look at qtwebkit, but then again there's the problem of the user having to install a separate program.